# Adding JSON elements in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I can't find what is wrong with this code. I have a JSON object like this:

```js
{
  "books": [
    { "name": "name1", "price": "price1" },
    { "name": "name2", "price": "price2" },
    { "name": "name3", "price": "price3" },
    { "name": "name4", "price": "price4" },
    { "name": "name5", "price": "price5" }
  ]
}
```

I want to put books from this JSON object in a table of 2 columns and rows, depending of the length of the JSON object. Here is my code:

```js
var jsonURL = "books.json";
$.getJSON(jsonURL, function(json) {
  var count = 0;

  function allBooks() {
    for (var i = 0; i < json.books.length; i++) {
      if (count == 2) {
        count = 0;
        $('#table > tbody:last').append('<tr></tr>');
      } else
        $('#table > tbody:last-child').append('<td><span>' + json.books[i].name + '</span>' + '<br><span>' + json.books[i].price + '</span></td>');
      count++;
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<div>
<button onclick="allBooks()"></button>
<table id="table" >
    <tr>

    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: `json.books[i].length` ? It should be `json.books.length`

Comment: My bad. But still doesn't work

Comment: Can we see more code? When are you calling allBooks()?

Comment: You have syntax errors, learn how to debug using the console

Comment: Also, you have invalid JSON

Comment: This might help: https://jsfiddle.net/ek0pnuss/

Comment: @RayonDabre I want two column in a row

Comment: As usual, I guess the reference to JSON is irrelevant and all you have a this point is a regular JavaScript object.

Comment: you havn't call the function `allbooks()` yet!!

Comment: @IQ246 where are you calling `allBooks()`? you need to call the function for it to run.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález JSON works fine at me I'm using it in other  methods

Comment: no you must call the function into `$.getJSON` method.

Answer (score 1):

You must define your functions within the proper scope.

As you have it, `allBooks` is defined inside `$.getJSON` so calling it in `onclick` **will not work.**

Try moving `$.getJSON` inside the function:

```
function allBooks() {
  var jsonURL = "books.json";
  $.getJSON(jsonURL, function(json) {
    var count = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < books.length; i++) {
      var book = books[i];
      // Appends a row with two cells to #table
      $('#table').append("<tr><td>"+book.name+"</td><td>"+book.price+"</td></tr>");
    }
  }
}
```